Problem with drag & drop via OLE in Delphi, IDropTarget is not called
I want to do drag & drop from Windows Explorer to my app via OLE interface IDropTarget. How do I detect if OLE communication is working well? For now, RegisterDragDrop function is working fine. But I can't get a call to my DragEnter function when dragging starts. How can I check that OLE is working fine and that dragging somehow starts? Why I can't get DragEnter function to run? Here is some nice theory: https://delphidabbler.com/articles/article-24
I can't get any of these functions to work or be called. What is wrong? How do I check if OLE can detect drag-drop in the first place?
function DragEnter(const dataObj: IDataObject; grfKeyState: Longint;  pt: TPoint; var dwEffect: Longint): HResult; stdcall;

function DragOver(grfKeyState: Longint; pt: TPoint; var dwEffect: Longint): HResult; stdcall;

function DragLeave: HResult; stdcall;

function Drop(const dataObj: IDataObject; grfKeyState: Longint; pt: TPoint; var dwEffect: Longint): HResult; stdcall;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/dragdrop
I'm stopped at point 1 or 2.
RegisterDragDrop(Handle, Handler);

Handle: 722688
Handler: TFileDropTarget($23747B02490) as IDropTarget

I have a pointer to IDropTarget, but it does not call IDropTarget.DropEnter function when I start the drag operation. Why not? How can I check this?
I called:
RegisterDropTarget(TFileDropTarget.Create(FileDragEnter, FileDragOver, FileDragDrop, FileDragLeave));

No result. IDropTarget.DragEnter is not called. How do I detect if IDropTarget is called properly? I need to transfer a file between Windows Explorer to my program.

Note that Windows doesn't support drag and drop between programs running at different integrity levels since Wndows Vista. Programs running with Administrator prviledge will not be a drop target for stuff dragged from programs not running with Administrator priviledge.

@Brian It can work if you handle WM_DROPFILES (DragAcceptFiles()) instead of IDropTarget (RegisterDragDrop()), and then use ChangeWindowMessageFilter/Ex() to allow the WM_DROPFILES, WM_COPYDATA, and (undocumented) WM_COPYGLOBALDATA (0x0049) messages. ChangeWindowMessageFilter/Ex() doesn't work with IDropTarget, though. The alternative is to either 1) enable UIAccess=true for your app (this has very restrictive requirements, though), or 2) run a non-elevated process to accept the drag and then IPC the data into your elevated app.
